# Docker - Ownership lost after mounting a single file

Tags: docker, permissions, dockerfile, chmod, chown

I'm trying to get used to Docker and I now stumbled upon a delicate problem which I was not able to solve yet.

(Im working on Windows 10, but the same problem applies to Debian)

I would like to run my containers entrypoint as a non-root, which is already working. However, I would like to have a file where I already set the permissions that my application requires (user:usergrp and chmod 600) like so:

```
 touch /app/application.properties && \
 chown user:usergrp /app/application.properties && \
 chmod 600 /app/application.properties
```

This does in fact work. If I just run the container without any mounts, I can see that its setup correctly:

```
-rw-------    1 user usergrp         0 Jan  6 18:32 application.properties
```

However, when I override the file using a single file mount, the ownership changes to **root:root**. In contrary, the permissions stay as 600.

My confusion comes from the fact that volume mounts and single file mounts work differently here. In my Dockerfile I also have a directory which is overridden by a mount and it **keeps ownership and permissions**.

How can I achieve that the ownership is preserved for a single file mount, or do I have to solve it differently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your single file mounts command ?

Comment: I mount it using "-v [absolutePath]:/app/application.properties."

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this issue, and I found that some command combinations will cause file becomes to root, such as `--mount source=test.properties,target=/app/test.properties`.

Try this way to keep ownership and permissions for a single file. This command combination works fine on my machine.

```
--mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/test.properties,target=/app/test.properties
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for two reasons. First, $(pwd) does not work stating "docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: '$(pwd)/test.properties' mount path must be absolute.".

Also, if I use your mount command and an absolute path, it still gets mounted as root:root on the VM.

I tried it using debian and alpine as the image.

Here is how I create the user and group:
RUN addgroup --system usergrp && adduser --system --ingroup usergrp user